# How do I make a progress bar with letters that get "filled in"?

Tags: graphics, loading

I want to make a progress bar made of text! I have two images: One with the text in gray, the other coloured:

[image: gray progress bar] [image: colored progress bar]

As my game is loading, I want the letters to "fill up" with color:

[image: filling-up progress bar]

They would start out gray, then fill in.

I was thinking of overlaying a transparent rectangle over the gray image, then stretching the transparent rectangle to match the progress. But then the background will be coloured too. I want *only the letters* to be coloured!

How can I do this?

Comment: I wrote [an answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69561/how-do-i-create-a-world-healing-wave-effect/69693#69693) a month ago on creating a "world healing wave" effect with a clip region. (Might be useful due to the similarities.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how this feature would be implemented in your specific development environment, but the solution to the problem you describe is [masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29#Image_masks).

Basically, apply a mask to the progress bar in the shape of your letters and then the stretched rectangle won't be rendered outside the mask.

Comment: I understand the idea behind this, thanks for the link. I should be able to get it going now.

Answer (score 2):

If your ui system uses a layering concept you can do this:

1. Have an image with the letters having alpha of 0 (front layer).
2. Have a quad which is the "unloaded" colour, scaled to the same
   dimensions as your front image(back layer)
3. In the middle layer, have  a quad with the "loaded" colour, scaled
   to some suitably small value on the x axis, then scale it up as the
   percentage of loaded resources increases up to 100% of the width of
   the front image.

Note, if you are doing this with opengl, you will need to do some translation work too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, but doing this with modern OpenGL does not really differ from D3D.

Comment: Indeed, the method is exactly the same, even if the code differs somewhat.