# Animated Energy/Combo Bar (Unity 4.6)

Tags: unity, animation, gui

How could I achieve the animated Combo bar effect used in Ski Safari / Ski Safari: Adventure time? Preferably with Unity 4.6 UI. General explanations also welcome!

Links to videos showing the wanted effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnfCkqiM890#t=4m46s
and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqj61liRJ74#t=7m00s

Comment: By "animated", do you mean using an animated image for the "filled" part of the [progress bar](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25537/how-do-i-make-a-progress-bar-with-letters-that-get-filled-in)? I imagine it's similar to a progress bar with a static image. Does that linked question help?

Comment: I figured it out. I used a mask with an animated sprite. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. You could post that as an answer here and mark it accepted to help future visitors find it. (Answering your own questions is totally OK.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to accomplish this effect in Unity by using the Mask component in UI and adding an animated sprite to it as a child. Also, big thanks to Anko for help.